# the convention how connecting lines connect the dots

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, vector, plot

I have two matrix, `x` and `y`.  `x` has size of `10` rows and `50` columns, and so is `y`.

My data is row-to-row paired. It means that the

```
x[0][:] <-> y[0][:]
x[1][:] <-> y[1][:]
x[2][:] <-> y[2][:]

......
x[49][:] <-> y[0][:]
```

When I use following command to do the plot, the

```
plot(x[:][:],y[:][:],'b-o')
```

or

```
plot(x,y,'b-o')
```

to do the plot, the '-' connects the dots in horizontal direction like following:

[image]

However, when I do only plot one row of signal:

```
plot(x[0][:],y[0][:],'b-o')
```

it looks correct:

[image]

I would like for the '-' to connect the dots in a horizontal fashion. Something like this:

[image]

in stead of doing a for loop, how do I do it in matrix format? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you transpose X and Y and then do the plot ?

Comment: Can you provice mock data ?

Comment: @OddNorg I suppose that would swap my x-axis and y-axis, which is not what I want.

Comment: I see. effect could be different depending on the original shape. This is why Ive asked for some mock data , by any chance are you trying to do a meshgrid ?

Comment: @OddNorg I would prefer not to arrange my x data in y-direction my my data in x-direction such that my x data get connected.

Comment: @OddNorg.......I'd probably do a loop.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some data to demonstrate.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.matrix(
    [
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]
    ]
)

y = x.transpose()

# Vertical Lines of grid:
plt.plot(x, y, 'b-o')
plt.show()
```

[image: vert]

```
# Horizontal Lines
plt.plot(x, y, 'b-o')
plt.show()
```

[image: hori]

```
# Together (this is what I think you want)
plt.plot(y, x, 'b-o')
plt.plot(x, y, 'b-o')
plt.show()
```

[image: grid]

If you try to concatenate them to do it in one large matrix it does some seemingly silly things by connecting a couple of points that we really do not want connected.

```
# sillyness
x1 = np.concatenate((x, y), axis=0)
y1 = np.concatenate((y, x), axis=0)

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'b-o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Since we do not know the data, Y might now be a perfect transpose of X, thus the solution would not work.

Comment: Absolutely agree, but that would be his problem to answer or reply to. Too bad he does not have any real example data in his question.